# How can I create a temporary sandbox to compile from source?

Tags: compiling

I want to follow the steps found [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141) in order to run League of Legends under Ubuntu. According to the guide, I have to compile wine from source because it needs some patches.

Compiling from source involves downloading quite a few dependency packages which I don't want to get mixed with the system and thus I'm wondering if there's a way to somehow isolate the whole "download dependencies packages and compile" process as I am only interested in the final wine binary.

By isolating the compile process I can just copy the resulting binary and do a simple delete on the sandbox whereas doing it the naive way would require a more complex cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into [arkose [image: Install arkose]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/arkose). As [it's manpage [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/arkose) says, it is a "tool to make sandboxing desktop application easy," but it can also be used for purposes like yours.

It's author, Stéphane Graber described how he uses it to keep from having to install many dependencies while doing development [on his blog](http://www.stgraber.org/2011/09/25/using-arkose-for-development-and-packaging/):

> Since I last reinstalled my laptop, I try to keep my usually insanely
>   long list of installed packages to a bare minimum. I’d usually have
>   hundreds if not thousands of libraries and development packages as
>   these are required by a bunch of packages I maintain or code I work
>   on.
>
> To achieve this and still be as productive as before (if not more),
>   I’m using arkose quite a lot to generate temporary dev/build
>   environment that are wiped as soon as I close the shell. This helps
>   maintain the number of extra libraries to a minimum, avoiding
>   situations where something mysteriously works fine on my laptop but
>   not on another machine and avoids the maintenance needed when dealing
>   with chroots.

Run, `arkose -h` in a terminal. This will create a container that has direct access to your home directory but uses copy-on-write for the rest of the file-system. When you're done, exit the shell and all your changes outside of `/home` (i.e. all the packages you installed) will be thrown away.

Comment: That's exactly what I as looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use http://www.playonlinux.com/en/forums.html just search their or LoL

Otherwise you could just use virtualbox or any other virtualization software